# Why is $I + (a) = R$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of a ring $R$ and let $(a)$ be the principal ideal generated by the element $a$ which lies in $R$ but not $I$.
Why does $R = I + (a)$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what "maximal ideal" means?

Comment: Is not contained in any ideal

Comment: Every ideal contains itself, so that definition doesn't make sense. If you don't know the definition, look it up — it should be in your textbook.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make the mathematical expressions more readable (mostly it involves wrapping math in dollar signs:  `$<math goes here>$`).  See this handy tutorial, so that you can make nicely formatted questions in the future:
  
http://tinyurl.com/MathJaxTutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I$ is a maximal ideal means if $J$ is any ideal of $R$ with $I \subseteq J$ then either $I = J$ or $J = R.$ In this case, take $J = I + (a).$ By the given condition, $J \neq I.$ So $J = R.$

Comment: cheers, I forgot that adding ideals gives an ideal

Comment: @user142775 You might find it helpful to first recall the well-known special-case for *principal* ideals: $\,i\,$ irreducible, $\,\ i\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\, (i,a) = 1,\, $ which can be interpreted in either ideal or gcd language.